# mysql not entering total number of rows into db from csv

Tags: php, mysql, sql, csv

I am wondering if there is a mysql or php setting that could limit the number of rows that you could enter into a mysql table.

I have this piece of code below, that works fine for small files like 1MB ones but its failing on a file that is 10mb

It manages to dump 22,000 rows into the table where as there are 222,000 rows in the file. Also the values inside the time_stamp change from something like  `2014-06-05` into `2014-06-05`

```
 $query_name = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '"
        . $file_path . 
        "' INTO TABLE `"
        . $this->table_name . 
         "` FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
         LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n' 
         IGNORE 1 LINES 
         (time_stamp,curr_property,curr_property_cost,day_property,day_property_cost,curr_solar_generating,curr_solar_export,day_solar_generated,day_solar_export,curr_chan1,curr_chan2,curr_chan3,day_chan1,day_chan2,day_chan3)
          ";
```

Could someone point out what i am doing wrong? I have googled for answers but couldn't find anything similar yet.

Comment: why don't you cut your file for 22000 lines and after that dump in database?

Comment: I fixed it just now, it had do with the post file size.